# nvim error on :so in Ubuntu WSL2

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, neovim

I have Ubuntu over WSL2 and I was following [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w7i4amO_zaE) on how to configure vim. My nvim installation didn't have the `.config` folder, so I created it and followed the video.

I placed an `init.lua` with a `print("hello")`, just like in the video, but I don't see any output, like he showed. Also, I tried the `:Ex` remap to `<leader>pv`, but the `:so` command shows an error saying:

> E471: Argument required

My feeling is that there's something missing in my setup, even though I followed all the tutorials so far.

How can I fix it?

Comment: What's the full path of your init.lua file? Is there an adjacent init.vim file? Have you tried giving :so an actual path that it's supposed to read?

Comment: Full path of init.lua: ~/.config/nvim no adjacent init.vim file, I didn't tried :so with a path, since the video didn't need it. Also in the video it doesn't appear to have a init.vim adjacent to the init.lua

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by figuring it out the ubuntu apt package is an older version (0.6.1) and I needed a newer one in order to work (0.9.0)